# Beginner in R , try hist function with vector

Tags: r, histogram

I have tried the function `hist(y)` for `y=c(1,2,3,4,5)` but the frequency of 1 is 2.0 ,why?

Comment: I think it's 1:2 not 1? Try changing `right` to FALSE and see.

Comment: If you are working with discrete values, you should use a bar chart rather than a histogram. See `?barplot` for details on constructing such a figure in base R.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a mistake. The histogram is showing the frequency of values within the range 1 to 2. By default, `hist` sets `right` to `TRUE` which means the intervals are right closed. Change that to `FALSE` and you will have a histogram that is left closed hence turning the frequency of 4-5 to 2. For more details, please see `help(hist)`.

**Excerpt from the docs**:

> The definition of histogram differs by source (with country-specific biases). R's default with equi-spaced breaks (also the default) is to plot the counts in the cells defined by breaks. Thus the height of a rectangle is proportional to the number of points falling into the cell, as is the area provided the breaks are equally-spaced.
>
> The default with non-equi-spaced breaks is to give a plot of area one, in which the area of the rectangles is the fraction of the data points falling in the cells.

**Scenario 1:**

```
hist(1:5)
```

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

```
hist(1:5, right = FALSE)
```

[image: *enter image description here*]

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you only have four boxes.  The first box is indicating the number of 1's *and* 2's. You can get something more like what you were expecting by specifying the breakpoints.

```
hist(y, breaks=seq(0.5,5.5,1))
```

[image: Histogram with 5 boxes]

Answer (score 2):

You may need to look at `bin` in a [histogram plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). a histogram is different from a fequency barplot.
you can try :

```
barplot(table(y))
```

[image]